# Novel search: A man searching for his brother in Africa starts a chase through different realities/dimensions

Tags: story-identification

I might be mixing up several books, I hope I'm not, it's been 20 years since I read the books.

I want to say it was a series of books.
Each book could have been written by a different writer.

From memory it starts off in the late 1800's/early 1900's a man has gone to Africa to search for his lost brother. Weird/implausible stuff starts happening as they travel up a river, I want to say the Congo, and eventually they enter another realm. As they chase after clues to his brother they traverse a reality roughly each book.

At some point I want to say there is train imagery used as well as an iceberg with reference to Mary Shelly's monster(I could be mixing this up with another book)

Comment: it could be multi author

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm guessing Philip Jose Farmer's shared world series ["The Dungeon"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dungeon_series), six novels by four authors who are not Farmer.

> The books follow nineteenth century explorer Clive Folliot as he
>   travels through a multilayered dungeon world attempting to find his
>   twin brother Neville. Along the way, he forms a group of similarly
>   lost creatures and persons, and must battle the pawns and agents of
>   the Dungeon's mysterious alien masters.

Volume One, The Black Tower by Richard Lupoff

[image]

Comment: YES! that's it - thank you so much!