# Story identification sci fi series two authors early nineties

Tags: story-identification

In the early nineties, I was reading a science fiction series that was written by two authors. The series was not complete at the time, but there were probably like four to six books in the series.

I don't remember much about the book except for a few peculiarities. At the beginning of the series, it is clear that one author is attempting to introduce computer-based slang for the characters. I think one character actually says "shove that up your disk drive", or something to that effect. I suspect that the other author wrote the second book, because this was completely dropped, and then reintroduced in later books. Even as a young person, this produced quite a jarring effect.

The only other thing I can remember about the series is that there was some kind of female insectoid creature. At one point, she loses a limb, but isn't too worried because she can grow it back.

Perhaps that is too little to go on, but I figured I'd try.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Six novels, four authors. [Philip José Farmer's The Dungeon](https://www.goodreads.com/series/40508-philip-jos-farmer-s-the-dungeon)

> The books follow nineteenth century explorer Clive Folliot as he travels through a multilayered dungeon world attempting to find his twin brother Neville. Along the way, he forms a group of similarly lost creatures and persons, and must battle the pawns and agents of the Dungeon's mysterious alien masters.

One of the group Clive assembles is a psychic, matronly spider-being named 'Shriek'. There was also the human woman 'User Annie' from Clive's future, who indeed, spoke the computer patois.

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of [this answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/69195/novel-search-a-man-searching-for-his-brother-in-africa-starts-a-chase-through-d/69196#69196) from last year.

Comment: Wow, that is amazing. I'm not sure how to deal with duplicates for story identification on this site.. the clues provided in the other question were not similar enough for me to find it on this site, so maybe it isn't truly a duplicate? Just two different questions with the same answer? Anyway, this answer really made my day, thanks.

Comment: That's why I said the *answer* was a dupe, not the question.  :)